# Clarification on Message-Integrity calculation for ICE connectivity Check using STUN binding request

Tags: webrtc, stun

RFC 8445 states in relevant parts:

```
 7.2.2.  Forming Credentials

        A connectivity-check Binding request MUST utilize the STUN short-term
        credential mechanism.

        The username for the credential is formed by concatenating the
        username fragment provided by the peer with the username fragment of
        the ICE agent sending the request, separated by a colon (":").

        The password is equal to the password provided by the peer.

        For example, consider the case where ICE agent L is the initiating
        agent and ICE agent R is the responding agent.  Agent L included a
        username fragment of LFRAG for its candidates and a password of
        LPASS.  Agent R provided a username fragment of RFRAG and a password
        of RPASS.  A connectivity check from L to R utilizes the username
        RFRAG:LFRAG and a password of RPASS.  A connectivity check from R to
        L utilizes the username LFRAG:RFRAG and a password of LPASS.  The
        responses utilize the same usernames and passwords as the requests
        (note that the USERNAME attribute is not present in the response).
```

But RFC 5389 on STUN describing the computation of the MESSAGE-INTEGRITY field and specifically short-term credentials, states:

```
  For short-term credentials:
                      key = SASLprep(password)
```

QUESTION: 
  For calculating HMAC for message-integrity, neither the key nor the text over which HMAC is computed references any username fragments. Also, username does not play a role in fingerprint computation. So my question is: Where does username come into play in the STUN short-term credential mechanism when there is no trace of username in the request? Of course, ufrag and upassword are exchanged through SDP but how are they used to authenticate/validate a binding request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right the username has no impact on the MessageIntegrity, but it should be in the STUN packet under the username attribute.

You can see that [here](https://github.com/pion/ice/blob/master/agent.go#L1092-L1098) we assert that on the inbound message the username is `a.localUfrag+":"+a.remoteUfrag`

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot! The USERNAME attribute is needed for message integrity and I inadvertently missed it!

Comment: I think that if USERNAME is used solely for message integrity as it appears to be, then it should have been part of the message-integrity attribute's value - a composite value as in address (family, port ipaddress). Just a thought.

Comment: the username (or rather ufrag pair) can be used for demultiplexing multiple sessions on the same port pair (or 5-tuple)

Comment: @Sean DuBois  Can you point me to the SASL prep function implementation in Pion for setting USERNAME attribute.  Do you use "The PLAIN Simple Authentication and Security Layer (SASL) Mechanism" RFC 4616? Thanks

Comment: We don't do any SASLPrep looks like! I haven't touched this code in two years, but https://github.com/pion/stun/blob/9e964187770c0ac8ffb8f5fc96aa9b8e89d8aa52/textattrs.go#L4 just casts to a `[]byte` -- I don't believe WebRTC uFrag/uPwd rules ever allow any characters that need to be sanitized, so this never has been an issue!

Comment: @SeanDuBois I will look into it but a quick look shows that you also support long term credentials. I think from a WebRTC perspective, ICE connectivity checks use STUN binding requests which only uses short term credentials.  Perhaps you are supporting long term credentials for TURN support? I am going off topic here and am not too conversant with TURN details...

Comment: Yea! We have a turn implementation also github.com/pion/turn, so need to support all the STUN messages/attributes for that. (hopefully I am answering your question!)

Comment: ufrag is defined as `4*256ice-char` which is `ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "/"` so SASLPrep is a no-op

Comment: @SeanDuBois You and Philipp Hancke are certainly clarifying doubts in what is certainly a very interesting area.  The comment by Phillip that SASLPrep is a no-op for the use-case clarifies the confusion in this area and lets me avoid reading on the gory details of SASL.